# Create a 1-D array that shows the indexes of a 2-D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, dimensions, cells

Lets say, we have the following two-dimensional array in Matlab:

```
A=[0 451
   0 446
   0 543
   .....]
```

etc. I want to create another, one-dimensional array, that will do this:
For example, lets call the 1-D array `B`, `B(1)` will "show" to `[0 451]`. B(2) will "show" to `[0 446]`, B(3) will "show" to `[0 543]` and so on.I hope that my desired result is pretty clear to anyone who could give me a bit help.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. By "show" do you simply mean "display" or "point to" or "return the value". Does B(1) have to be able to receive assignment (ex `B(1)=[0 123]`) or is it just an expression that return a value (ex: `newValPair = B(1)`)?

Comment: Not sure how A is a 2-D array, are there some new rows missing? Is there a reason you cannot just reshape it into a 2 column matrix i.e. B=[0, 451; 0, 446; ...], then call B(1, :).

Comment: @Hoki I meant "point to". My apologies if i was not clear enough. B(1) has to be able to receive assignment, exactly as you said.

Comment: @nivag A is a 2-D array, there are not any rows missing. I just wanted to create an 1-D array, whose cells would "point to" the respective cells of the B table. Problem solved with the acceptable answer below. :)

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Done, sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

```
a=1:10
split_a1=(reshape(a,2,[])).';
```

Access `split_a1` as `split_a1(1,:),...,split_a1(5,:);`.

```
split_a2=mat2cell(a,1,2*ones(1,numel(a)/2));
```

Access `split_a2` as `split_a2{1},...,split_a2{5};`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it helped me to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you have just set is impossible, you are mixing the arrays and the Dimensions. 
As you have explained it, B is 2-D, and A is 1-D. You can do what you want by doing this:

```
j=0; 
i=1;
while i<=size(A,2)/2;
    j=j+1;
    B(i,1)=A(j);
    j=j+1;
    B(i,2)=A(j);
    i=i+1;
end
```

Comment: You can achieve the same thing with: `reshape(A,2,[]).'`

Comment: @arodrisa Thank you for the answer but the other one solution worked better for me.

Comment: No problem, but you described something different now :)